# Querystring parameters in POST request

Tags: python, django, httprequest

In django, What happens to querystring parameters when request is made through **POST**?

In my application, i am sending a query parameter `"update=1"`, while submitting the form using **POST**.

Ideally this parameter should be available in `request.GET` querydict, but strangely this is appearing in both `request.GET` and `request.POST`.

My form html looks something like below:

```
<form action="my/profile?update=1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" />
</form>
```

Inside my view, i am writing below code to access the parameter.

```
updated = request.GET.get('update')
```

Interestingly both GET and POST work in above expression, with **GET** *querydict* containing only one parameter i.e. `update` and **POST** containing two parameters i.e. `update & first_name`.

So is this correct behavior?

Comment: Could you show the code of your form and view?

Comment: Updated form and view code.

Comment: Are you sure that `request.POST` contains both `update` and `first_name` parameter? I've just created a simple form, submitted it and I do see `request.POST` = `<QueryDict: {u'first_name': [u'test']}>` and `request.GET` = `<QueryDict: {u'update': [u'1']}>`.

Comment: I tried creating another test application and interestingly, POST and GET parameters were fine. Looks like there is something else which is causing this issue in my application.

Comment: Yup, theoretically POST parameters go in request body, GET in request url string. In think there is something in your django app that updates `request` object and mixes parameters. Could you show your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `INSTALLED_APPS`?